# matlab try to write the max function

Tags: matlab, max

I'm trying to write the max function of matlab:

```
B = max(A,B);
```

Is it correct?

```
for i=1:size(A,1)
    for j=1:size(A,2)
       if A(i,j) > B(i,j)
         B(i,j) = A(i,j);
       end
    end
end
```

thank you!

Comment: What happened when you tested it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you mean that `B = max(A,B)` should output a matrix containing at each index (i,j) the largest of either A(i,j) or B(i,j), then yes, it is correct (if you supply it with two-dimensional matrices A and B with `size(A)>=size(B)` )

The standard [max](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) function however does not exactly work like that. For example it can also handle higher dimensional matrix input, you can specify along which dimension you want to calculate maximum,...